# Remove Currency Formatting in VBA

Tags: excel, number-formatting, currency-formatting, vba

I am programmatically saving an Excel sheet as a CSV.

In this I want to clear the currency format in the worksheet and save only the value.

```
.ClearFormats //Works fine but it also demolishes the Date field.
```

Is there a way to clear only the currency/accounting formatting (Office 2010)

```
With wbkExcel
    For i = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
        .Worksheets(i).Cells.ClearFormats
        .Worksheets(i).SaveAs Filename:=extractPath & Fname & " " & .Worksheets(i).Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Next
End With
```

Comment: I can only think of checking the `NumberFormat` before clearing it

Comment: That does become slow as Peter mentions it below

Comment: @OrangeRind Is the Formatting the same for the entirety of each Column?  (i.e. could you just check the values in Row 2, and then change the Formatting for the whole `.Column` at once?)

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over all cells in a worksheet and check for its .Numberformat. If it is your currency format, apply .ClearFormats or change the format:

```
Sub ExportWithoutCurrencyFormat()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        For Each rng In ws.Cells
            If rng.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $" Then rng.NumberFormat = "0"
        Next rng
        ws.SaveAs Filename:=extractPath & Fname & " " & Worksheets(i).Name & _
            ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This will be pretty slow, as each cell will be accessed. A better approach would be to use a style for all currencies values that defines the currency format. Then all you'd need to do is to change to style, export the sheets - and if you wish change the style back to the original. you can change the style like this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Styles("My currency style").NumberFormat = "#.##0,00 €"
```

Comment: I had this idea - but as you also mention that it will be slow - and I have a decently large number of files that need to be processed. :)